# Checking if a byte is ascii printable

Tags: python

I am reading in a file using binary settings:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```

I am then reading the entire file into a variable:

```
x = f.read()
```

My problem is that I want to check if the bytes in x are ascii printable. So i want to compare the bytes to see if they are within the range of say 32-128 in decimal notation. What would be the easiest way to go about doing this?

I have toyed around with the ord() function, various hex functions since I have previously converted the bytes into hex elsewhere in my project, but nothing seems to be working.

I'm new to python but have experience in other languages. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: What if the file contains a new line? That is not printable?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I am using python3.5 @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Willem - newline is 10(decimal) which is less than 32 so outside OP's range 32-128

Comment: What do you want to do with the bytes that are not in your range? If you want to change them to say 255 the translate function can do the job with just one call.

Answer (score 4):

You could check each byte against `string.printable`.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'

printable_chars = bytes(string.printable, 'ascii')
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    printable = all(char in printable_chars for char in f.read())
```

For greater efficiency, O(1) vs O(n) for the set vs string lookup, use a set:

```
printable_chars = set(bytes(string.printable, 'ascii'))
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    printable = all(char in printable_chars for char in f.read())
```

Comment: Considering the length of `string.printable`, the O(n) lookup **might** actually be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to compare the bytes to see if they are within the range of say 32-128 in decimal notation

just do it ; )

```py
byte_str = b"".join(([ bytes(chr(i), 'ascii') for i in range(128) ]))

for byte in byte_str:
  if byte < 32 or 128 < byte:
    print(f"byte_str is not printable because of byte {repr(chr(byte))}")
    break
```

example result

```
byte_str is not printable because of byte '\x00'
```